# popen and fgets deadlock in _acrt_AppPolicyGetProcessTerminationMethodInternal

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I use [`popen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx) and then read child's stdout using [`fgets`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37dh6kf.aspx). However, sometimes parent deadlocks on `fgets` call, while child is stuck somewhere in crt internals trying to exit:

```
>   ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForSingleObject@12()   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpDrainWorkQueue@4()   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!LdrpLoadDllInternal() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_LdrpLoadDll@20() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!LdrLoadDll()  Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!LoadLibraryExW() Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!try_get_function() Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!___acrt_AppPolicyGetProcessTerminationMethodInternal@4()   Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!exit_or_terminate_process()    Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!common_exit()  Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!_exit()    Unknown
    Base.UnitTest.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() Line 262 C++
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown


ucrtbase.dll    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll    10.0.16299.248 (WinBuild.160101.0800)   15-May-87 01:52 764A0000-765B7000   [103908] Base.UnitTest.exe
```

Here's the stack from parent:

```
>   ntdll.dll!_NtReadFile@36()  Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!ReadFile()   Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!_read_nolock() Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!_read()    Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!common_refill_and_read_nolock<char>()  Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!__fgetc_nolock()   Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!common_fgets<char>()   Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!_fgets()   Unknown
    Base.UnitTest.exe!ChildProcess::run() Line 183  C++
```

When this deadlock happens parent already has all the output that child produced. Child on its own does not deadlock. Any ideas what could be wrong and what is that AppPolicyGetProcessTerminationMethodInternal? This doesn't happen all the time, only sometimes, as it's a unit test and runs frequently on a build farm.

Comment: Would you please share your code?

Comment: It's part of large code base, difficult to share, but it simply comes down to popen and fgets blocking because child doesn't exit (which would make fgets return 0 in parent process and unblock the read look).

Comment: Can you prepare a [mcve] with just the `popen` (with the same program you pass to `popen`) and `fread` call? Does it have the same result?

Comment: FWIW, it's trying to load the "api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-2" API set, which loads "kernel.appcore.dll", in order to call `AppPolicyGetProcessTerminationMethod`. From what I can tell in the debugger, this gets called to look up the current exit policy, i.e. whether to call `ExitProcess` or `TerminateProcess`. Loading the API set appears to be deadlocked in your case, one would assume because something else is holding the loader lock. This doesn't answer why this deadlock only happens when stdout is a pipe. Try redirecting the child's stdout to a file in CMD.

Comment: One interesting observation: deadlock does not happen on single run. Only if parent starts a child *then kills it* and then starts another child and tried to read it. If there was no first killed child then this never deadlocks, otherwise it happens sometimes.

Comment: @eryksun - *something else is holding the loader lock* - no. the current thread is hold this critical section. the `LdrpDrainWorkQueue` wait on `LdrpWorkCompleteEvent` or `LdrpLoadCompleteEvent` (guess this). need look call stacks of all another threads in process

Comment: @Pablo I tried to create mcve and as usual the problem doesn't show up there. However, I tried to dig and seems that I was able to figure out what component affects: [breakpad](https://github.com/google/breakpad). When I compile my tests without breakpad I don't get these hangs.

Comment: @RbMm, I can reproduce this deadlock if I load a DLL in a worker thread that blocks in `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`. Apparently, `LdrpDrainWorkQueue` is waiting for the DLL's process-attach work item to complete.

Comment: @eryksun - `LdrpDrainWorkQueue` (some ["src"](https://pastebin.com/KEdjit3c) ) wait for all entries in `LdrpWorkQueue` will be removed and processed. how in more details you reproduce this ? simply interesting look under debugger

Comment: @RbMm, ok, when it enters `LdrpDrainWorkQueue` for the main thread, the argument is `WaitLoadComplete` (0), and the TEB `LoadOwner` value is 0 in this thread and 1 in the worker thread that's blocking in `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, and `LdrpWorkInProgress` is 1. The first pass through the loop, `LdrpLoadCompleteEvent` is already set and the `NtWaitForSingleObject` wait doesn't block. In the second pass it does block. When the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` finally completes, the main thread resumes with `LdrpWorkInProgress` now 0, so in this pass `LdrpWorkInProgress` and `LoadOwner` are set, and it returns.

Comment: Any ideas for workarounds? For now I print a cookie from child before it exits and when parent reads the cookie it knows child is about to exit. From this point I start a thread that will kill child in 100ms if popen/fgets gets stuck for more than 100ms.

Comment: @eryksun - yes. you correct. i also [reproduce](https://prnt.sc/iqi5y8) this. early loader acquire loader lock at very begin of dll load process and release at the end. but now only [calling dll entry points](https://prnt.sc/iqi98k) was inside this lock. loading dll and prepare it was now outside loader lock. (for protect dll list used another srw lock - `LdrpModuleDatatableLock`). also loader lock acquired on [thread start/exit](https://prnt.sc/iqi6vb). so here really loader deadlock - some thread hung in dll entry point during thread start/exit or dll load/unload

Comment: @Pavel - how i say at begin - *need look call stacks of all another threads in process*. some *another* thread hung in *DllMain* during start or exit. so you need look - what else threads exist in process - dump it stack. problem not in main thread which stack you dump but in some another thread in child process

Comment: *From this point I start a thread that will kill child in 100ms if popen/fgets gets stuck for more than 100ms* - this not a solution. *If there was no first killed child then this never deadlocks* - so may be simply never kill child's?, which is always bad (kill process)

Comment: I wrote ChildProcess class to wrap popen, as part of unit tests I verify things like killing a child after timeout etc. The mystery is that child that hangs is unrelated in any way to another child that was killed before the hung child even started. Child process does not have any other threads in my code, breakpad however starts a thread that waits to handle crashes. Might be realated, as disabling breakpad fixed the deadlock as well.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment seem to be incorrect. Child process that gets deadlocked does not have any other threads when it deadlocks on exit. Parent has breakpad thread, but I don't see any issues in parent process: it's simply stuck waiting for the child.

Comment: Also, I get this deadlock without killing any children. I have a unit test to start 50 child processes simultaneously and each one of them simply prints "OK" to stdout, and then parent verifies the result. I always get a few children locked up on exit.

Comment: The child is stuck in `LdrpDrainWorkQueue` without any other thread in the process? That's not a deadlock scenario. It's hung for some other reason. In cdb or windbg, `~` lists all threads, and `~Ns` switches to thread N, and `k` prints a stack trace. Make sure the debugger is set up with the public symbols from Microsoft (e.g. using `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH`). Attach to the hung child process, and check `?? @$teb->LoadOwner` in the thread (apparently the only thread) that's blocked in the `NtWaitForSingleObject` call made from `LdrpDrainWorkQueue`. Also check `dd ntdll!LdrpWorkInProgress l1`.

Comment: I use visual studio, and children don't have any threads other than the main one. See my answer, that's the exact reason why I was seeing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is caused by breakpad's [use of TermianteThread](https://github.com/google/breakpad/blob/67649c61853108eb0c29703f6ff0db42e9d69f10/src/client/windows/handler/exception_handler.cc#L359) when cleaning up on destruction:

If I compile with `#define BREAKPAD_NO_TERMINATE_THREAD 1` then I do not get deadlock on child exit.

Comment: Maybe @RbMm can explain this. Apparently it works, but it makes no sense to me how terminating the thread that executes the `ExceptionHandlerThreadMain` method causes the loader to lock up in the main thread when trying to load "api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-2.dll". The breakpad code actually warns about potential deadlocks when this no-terminate macro is defined (e.g. if it's a DLL, it can lead to deadlock between `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` and `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`).

Comment: afaik LoadLibrary shouldn't be used in dllmain, perhaps their comment it related to that.